# Drush make, git repository checkout specific subdirectory

Tags: 7, version-control, drush

I've got a make file in which I want to pull in a remote Git repository and only fetch a subdirectory. I've tried as following:

```
projects[example_module][type] = "module"
projects[example_module][download][type] = "git"
projects[example_module][download][url] = "git@bitbucket.org:team/example_modules.git"
projects[example_module][download][subtree] = "example_module_subdir"
```

Though, this creates a `example_module` folder where I expect it to be, though it contains the entire repository. What am I overlooking? Is this impossible? (using `Drush 7.0.0`)

Answer (score 1):

The `[subtree]` only works if the download is an archive.
See [Project download options](http://docs.drush.org/en/7.x/make/#project-download-options) page for drush 7.x.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with public repo you can play with the zip file generated by the repository

You need to open the zip file to get the structure of files inside the zip. And reproduce the same structure in the *subtree* parameter(github for example add a prefix with the tag to the directory inside the zip)

Example

```
libraries[views_civicrm_documents][destination] = "modules/contrib"
libraries[views_civicrm_documents][directory_name] = "views_civicrm_documents"
libraries[views_civicrm_documents][download][type] = "get"
libraries[views_civicrm_documents][download][url] = "https://github.com/CiviCooP/org.civicoop.documents/archive/refs/tags/v1.2.zip"
libraries[views_civicrm_documents][download][subtree] = "org.civicoop.documents-1.2/drupal/views_civicrm_documents"
```